# Filemaker Server 14 service will not start

Tags: filemaker

After reboting the Filemaker 14.4 server service is not starting anymore.
Nothing that I know about has changed.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you starting manually or rely on auto-startup option?

Answer (score 0):

As it seams this preferency file got corupted, at least it was empty:

C:\Program Files\FileMaker\FileMaker Server\Data\Preferences\dbs_config.xml

So I replaced it with a backup and all is fine now.